# Drupal My Account Block Personalisation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

When users login into my new Drupal site they and go their my Account page, they are greeted with several options including the ability to change their times zones. Weirdly they are also greeted with a Customization block to switch on or off the Main Menu. However the configuration for this is set to no personalisation and is called superfish not Main-Menu. How can i find out what is setting this to allow users to customize?

[image: Strange Customisation option appearing for users]

thanks

Lee

Answer (score 1):

It most certainly is a permissions issue.  Go to your permissions logged in as an administrator and remove permission to personalize blocks for whatever role your users are.

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: I have tried rebuilding the permissions but this option is still available to authenticated uvers. This is the HTML behind that option. Personalize blocks<input type="checkbox" id="edit-block-system-main-menu" name="block[system][main-menu]" value="1" checked="checked" class="form-checkbox" />  <label class="option" for="edit-block-system-main-menu">Main menu </label>

</div>

Comment: OK found out what was causing this. Although my sub theme didn;t have this option set on the block the admin theme did have the personalise option set and it seems this was coming through to the sub theme! grrr.